# retrieve data from a table in a json feed Angular 4

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a function that returns this result:

```
    {id: 20, dateCreation: 1517324655450, auteurCreation: "bel", dateModification: 1530544886148, auteurModification: "user", …}
    auteurCreation:"bel"
    auteurModification:"user"
coupesTechniquesDescription:Array(1)
0:{id: 15, hauteurReference: 2, commentaireReference: "test"}
length:1
__proto__
:Array(0)
dateCreation:1517324655450
id:20
```

i want to save : `coupesTechniquesDescription` in a variable,
the goal is to get the list of `coupesTechniquesDescription` and use the first index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. get the object right out of `res`:

```
// define the variable above your constructor
private coupesTechniquesDescription;

constructor(...){
    this.technicalservice.find(this.id).subscribe((res) => { 
        this.coupesTechniquesDescription = res.coupesTechniquesDescription[0];

        console.log(this.coupesTechniquesDescription);
    }, 
    (err) => { console.log("Erreur"); });

}
```

Comment: the jsonObject is res.json ?
here the code of function
this.technicalservice.find(this.id).subscribe((res) => {
                    
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Erreur");
        });